# Unity: Flip 2D GameObject(Clone) while GetKeyDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, flip

My problem is when I instantiate a GameObject, it should flip like my Player
but it's just flipping arround when im turn left.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class beam : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform firePoint;
public move dino;

void Awake()
{
    dino = GetComponent<move>();
    dino = FindObjectOfType<move>();
    firePoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("spawn").transform;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {      
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    transform.position = firePoint.position;
}
void Update ()
{
    if (dino.GetComponent<move>().facingRight == false)
    {
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

}
}
```

For example: my Player is facing right side, the "Beam" is facing right too but when my Player is facing left side the "Beam" switches between-1 and +1

I hope you understand what I mean. Please some help :)

Comment: is it sprite? or 3d?

Comment: it is a sprite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the fast flip in the update method: while dino not face right flip it like crazy! change *= to = and it should work. Or if it is already scaled then do this:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (dino.GetComponent<move>().facingRight == false)
    {
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x = Mathf.Abs(theScale.x) * -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

### Note:

It's better to use `SpriteRenderer.FlipX = true/false` rather than scale.

### Another Note:

If you use [batching](https://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html), non-uniform scale and flip are deadly. use multiple sprites and switch between them.

Comment: You Sir are Awesome! `theScale.x = Mathf.Abs(theScale.x) * -1;` worked for me!

Comment: @OliverSradnick Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) his answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you too @Programmer :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I always use scale*-1 and didn't even know that SpriteRenderer.flipX and flipY exist. Got that from your answer and I think it is useful. One correction though, I think your `Sprite.FlipX = true/false` should be `SpriteRenderer.FlipX = true/false`. `Sprite` is a valid Unity class but does not have `FlipX`  and `FlipX` variables . `SpriteRenderer` does.

Comment: @Programmer you are right I guess I was being lazy! and FlipX and FlipY are safe because they are additive to scale. imagine a case where scale is animated and FlipX changes in code.

Comment: Haven't really used so much animation in 2D but will start using the Flipx variable. Good to know that!